# Image getting corrupt in bluetooth transfer

Tags: android, image, bluetooth, text-files, chunks

I modified bluetooth chat (android sdk sample project) example to transfer images and text files. On receiver end, buffer is 1024 bytes and i am getting data in chunks of byte array. 
On receiver side, I combined byte array chunks by saving them in FileOutputstream which is written in a file. 
It works well for text file. 
But in case of image, it is not providing perfect results. Although image is shown on receiver side, its corrupted. It has lots of green and blue color over image. 
According to me, its because of combining chunks to make image. Any idea how this can be solved.How can i combine chunks of byte array to make exact image. Image can be in any format (jpg, png, jpeg etc) Any help will be highly appreciated.